# Possible to build query without DbContext instance?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dbcontext

I am using Entity Framework 5. I would like to build a query (DbQuery?) then execute it on a DbContext. Is it possible?

Normally, I would perform a query like this:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    var nike = db.Products.Where(p => p.Brand == "Nike").OrderBy(p => p.Name);
    foreach (var product in nike)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(product.Name);
    }
}
```

But can I construct the query before creating the DbContext, and then attach the query to a DbContext instance when I actually want to retrieve the data ?

Comment: Used this solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20023187/reexecuting-iqueryable-on-different-dbcontext-instance

Answer (score 2):

```
public IEnumerable<Products> GetProduct(MyDbContext db){
   //query created before-hand
   var nike = db.Products.Where(p => p.Brand == "Nike").OrderBy(p => p.Name);
   return nike;
}

//and then in your method:
using (var db = new MyDbContext()){
   var nike = GetProduct(db); //MyDbContext object attached here.
   foreach(var product in nike){
     Debug.WriteLine(product.Name);
   }
}
```

Maybe this is what you wanted to do? I am not sure.

Comment: There would also be the possibility to use [Compiled Queries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be following:

```
public Func<bool,Products> Filter()
{
    return i => i.Brand == "Nike"
}
public Func<bool,Products> Filter(string brandName)
{
    return i => i.Brand == brandName;
}


//usage:
db.Products.Where(Filter());
//or
db.Products.Where(Filter("Nike"));
```

Currently I cannot test, but it might be that you have to use `Expression<Func<bool,Brand>>`.
Can someone confirm that?