# Reexecuting IQueryable on different DbContext instance?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm creating a repository layer to encapsulate `DbContext`.
I would like to expose a fluent interface for building query, and dispose and create a new `DbContext` every time after a query request is sent:

```
var repo = new EntityRepository();

repo = EntityRepository.FilterByAge(30).FilterByGender("Male");
var people = repo.GetPeople();
  // GetPeople() should send the request, get the result, then dispose
  // the old DbContext and create a new one

repo = repo.FilterByOccupation("Programmer");
var programmers = repo.GetPeople();
  // the age and gender filters should still apply here
```

Currently in my `EntityRepository`, I have a private `DbContext` and a `IQueryable`. In the Filter methods, I append the Linq methods onto the `IQueryable`. Then after finishing a request, I do:

```
db.Dispose();
db = new EntityContext();
```

But this does not work when I try to do another request. It says the `DbContext` has been disposed.

How do I keep the same query for a new `DbContext`?

Comment: What is the reason behind disposing the context after each query? This is wrong, you should have strong arguments for doing something in such awkward way. Instead, your context should be injected into the repository so that the lifetime of the context is controlled from outside of the repository.

Comment: @WiktorZychla, I've got to disagree here. If something implements `IDisposable`, especially if provided by Microsoft, that by definition means it's disposable. Further it means there are unmanaged resource that need disposed. When leveraging something like this, even contexts, they should be wrapped in `using` statements and their lifetime should be very short.

Comment: There is no contradition, context should be disposed - true, should be short lifetime - true, let the repository live shortly. The problem is when the repository is responsible for controlling the lifetime of the context while it shouldn't. What if you want to share the same context in multiple repositories to control transactions for example? Also, IDisposable doesn't mean "using". For example, in a web application, you often want create the context for the request lifetime. You dispose in lately in the pipeline, in the Application_EndRequest, for example.

Comment: there is no reason to dispose your `DbContext` instance if you just plan on using another instance.

Comment: Sorry perhaps my question isn't clear. My focus isn't on disposing the`DbContext`. I understand that it is not nessecary to dispose `DbContext`, but I'm trying to avoid reusing the same instance because I'm writing this repository as a class library, so I don't want to assume the lifetime of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up keeping a list of "filters", which are anonymous functions that takes in `IQueryable` and return `IQueryable`. Then I apply them on a short-live `DbContext` :

**Repository:**

```
private IList<Func<IQueryable<Person>, IQueryable<Person>>> filters;

public Repository FilterByAge(int age)
{
    var _filters = new List<Func<IQueryable<Person>, IQueryable<Person>>>(filters);
    _filters.Add(q => q.Where(e => e.Age == age));
    return new Repository(_filters);
}

public Repository OrderByName()
{
    var _filters = new List<Func<IQueryable<Entity>, IQueryable<Entity>>>(filters);
    _filters.Add(q => q.OrderBy(e => e.Name));
    return new Repository(_filters);
}

private IQueryable<Person> ApplyFilters(AppContext db)
{
    var result = db.People;
    foreach (var filter in filters)
    {
        result = filter(result);
    }
    return result;
}

public IEnumerable<Person> GetPeople()
{
    IEnumerable<Person> people;
    using (var db = new AppContext())
    {
        people = ApplyFilters(db).ToList();
    }
    return people;
}
```

**Usage**

```
private Repository repo = new Repository();

var peopleOfThirty = repo.FilterByAge(30);
var orderedByName = peopleOfThirty.OrderByName();

if (wantOrder)
{
    return peopleOfThirty.GetPeople();
}
else
{
    return orderedByName.GetPeople();
}
```

It works for my purposes. However, please let me know if there is any problem doing it this way. Thanks!